# Can't create Docker network

Tags: docker

I've been able to start my Docker application without a problem but suddenly I get this error:

> failed to parse pool request for address space "LocalDefault" pool ""
>   subpool "": could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address
>   pool among the defaults to assign to the network

I'm running Docker 1.12.6.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Turns out [there's a limit](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23971#issuecomment-248585997) to the number of simultaneously active Docker networks and I hit that limit.

I got around the issue by removing all my networks:

```
docker network ls -q | xargs docker network rm
```

Comment: Or, in recent docker versions: `docker network prune`

Comment: This return error:
```
Error response from daemon: bridge is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
Error response from daemon: host is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
Error response from daemon: none is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
root@sham-Inspiron-7472:/home/sham/uol/RegistraSeguro/devstack# 
```

Answer (score 36):

I experienced this issue while running an OpenVPN client which was also my default route. Stopping the OpenVPN client worked around the issue.

Comment: Same happened to me with docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4 on Debian 8 (jessie) using OpenVPN.

Comment: If you need both openvpn and docker running here is possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45692255/7918 .

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-compose down
docker network prune
```

Comment: Please can you explain how this solves the problem? Take some time to read [answer] and edit your answer please. Code only answers may get deleted as they provide no information for future readers

Comment: It [could](https://github.com/maxking/docker-mailman/issues/85#issuecomment-349429246), and it's obivious how.