# Docker not working with a VPN due to network issues

Tags: docker, vpn

For some reason my VPN (NordVPN) is interfering with Docker:

```sh
make start
docker-compose -f docker-compose/docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose/docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
doCreating network "docker-compose_default" with the default driver
ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network
cmake: *** [Makefile:59: up_dev] Error 1
```

The issue seems to be to do with networking. I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it or fix it, though. After disabling my VPN and running `sudo systemctl restart docker`, Docker works fine.

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
- NordVPN Version 3.7.4

Comment: You may be at the maximum of created networks for docker. Try `docker network prune` and try again. And if it really is an issue with the VPN, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692255/how-make-openvpn-work-with-docker).

Comment: In my case `docker network prune` solved the network issue for macOS 10.15.2 and ProtonVPN 1.9.0. Docker would break on build with `ERROR [internal] load metadata` more precisely it `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0` as the request failed due to `Service Unavailable`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## TL;DR

The issue here is that `docker`/`docker-compose` is unable to find a suitable address range to assign a subnet to the a new internal network since the VPN adds routes for all IP addresses.

### Solutions:

1. manually [define the network and its address range](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network-configuration-reference) in `docker-compose.yml` or use an [existing one](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1) => requires changes in all your `docker-compose.yml` files which also may become hardly portable due to the hard coded addresses.
2. start `docker`/all your services before the VPN => probably not practicable in all cases
3. reconfigure the routing configuration of your VPN to exclude ranges to be used by docker => will add complexity to your VPN configuration and may leak traffic intended for VPN if done wrong

## Explanation

By default `docker-compose` [sets up a dedicated `docker network` for each project](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) i.e. a virtual bridge device on the docker host.

To assign a subnet range and gateway address to the network `docker` tries to select a range from a pool of possible ranges. It checks that the selected range does not overlap with a range/route already bound to a connected network device to prevent issues with colliding address ranges in use by the host.

The VPN on the other hand may add its own routes in order to redirect all traffic through the VPN tunnel. Because of this `docker` will not be able to find a "unused" address range to assign to the new network.

For more on this see [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692255/how-make-openvpn-work-with-docker) and the [respective issue on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/issues/779)

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me. Stop the running container and try with

`docker network prune`

Note: use with caution

Comment: It's working form me !!
Thank you

Comment: not for me, I could connect to internet, not anymore :|

Comment: I'm not sure why this has anything to do with a local docker build x.Dockerfile but when I did this, my network resolution started working again. I had a gitlab repository within a VPN network and even on the VPN, it wasn't working. I copied and pasted the gitlab clone url on my local machine (where I was running the docker build) and it worked fine. I did a network prune and then the docker build started working. I'm lost but now I'm found :) thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
docker-compose down
```

That will accomplish the following cleanup for you:

> Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes